# How can I check if a calendar with a given name already exists?

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

After the user grants me access to his calendar I would like to create a calendar dedicated to my application, so as not to litter users primary calendar. But if the same user grants the access the second time, the second calendar with the same name gets created, and so on. How can I check if the calendar already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CalendarList](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList)  returns a list of all of the [calendars](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars) a user has access to.  It basically the list displayed on the left hand menu, in the web application.

You can do [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) to retrieve a list of all of the calendar a user has then scan through the list to see if your calendar exists already.